# Display links inside text in literal component

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink, encode

I am displaying data from database with `Literal`.

```html
<asp:Literal ID="TextLiteral" Text='<%# Eval("Text")%>' Mode="Encode" runat="server">
```

I am using `Mode="Encode"` to prevent script injection. But I need to display links (like http://google.com) inside the text.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: use hyperlink instead

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a text-HTML conversion, such as [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

That way you can prevent script injection while still allowing simple HTML markup such as links, text formatting etc.

Comment: Could Markdown be used on ASP.NET?

Comment: @JiriZdvomka Yes it can. In fact you're using it right now. Stackoverflow uses ASP.NET and Markdown.

Comment: @JiriZdvomka To be more specific I believe SO uses Markdown Javascript library to render the output, but I've used a C# library for Markdown in the past.